# Globe and mail finance - is there something to pull similar financial data

Tags: api, finance

I was looking at the globe and mail finance site, and it has almost everything a person could want for real time stock and financial reports and if possible, mutual fund information. I was wondering if anybody knows what they use or a product that is similar?  I'm on a budget as I want to make very in depth stock/mutual fund portfolio tracker on my own. (Thus its my personal $)

From looking at other, older, stackoverflow questions:

- -Mergent - their free trial of their API's no longer work, also, you need to go through a salesperson even to just see it.
- -Yahoo finance - does not have financial reports (Balance sheets, cash flow etc)
- -Google finance - deprecated
- EDIT: Thompson Reuters - I contacted sales, they never answered. I used their "Email us form", they never responded.

Any ideas?